# How to sort data from newest to oldest records using VB.NET and MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, sorting, ms-access

I tried to use to sort records into DESC Auto number but it didn't work. Here's my code

`Access.ExecQuery("Select * From tbl_Monitoring ORDER BY Delivery Number DESC")`

the Delivery Number is Auto Number. Is there another way to sort records from newest to oldest??

Comment: If you had a DateAdded, or LastOrderDate, or DeliveryDate or any date, you could order by that (be sure it is an actual date column)

Answer (score 0):

if someone have the same problem I have here's the answer! Credits to Plutonix!

"If you had a DateAdded, or LastOrderDate, or DeliveryDate or any date, you could order by that (be sure it is an actual date column) – by Plutonix"

or you can sort it by `"Select * [from table_name] ODER BY [AUTONUMBER] DESC;"`

my fault Autonumbers can be sorted from highest to lowest

Comment: Mark this as the answer and people will know this question is answered :)

Comment: ah my bad i swear i saw someone do it before haha